# Opera Mini like software as Open Source

Tags: html, browser, opera

I'm looking for any(related?) opensource project that render web-pages at server side and deliver as images to client (mobiles?). Just like Opera Mini and SkyFire. So far, google does not give me a clue as  I can't figure it out which term to use. Could you guys give me a clue?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try searching for "proxy" as there may be an open source proxy that can use Webkit or similar to pre-render/optimize/collapse the page for you. As Alexander's post implies, though, it is more complicated than just rendering it to an image. Even a plain old HTTP proxy like Squid could be configured to cache and compress images such that mobile browsing is faster than it would be otherwise.

Comment: My native language is not supported by any major mobile phone OS, and my country just started giving mobile internet services. To let our people view webpages, I need to create an Opera Mini like software that renders webpages at server side (where we can render complex script texts).

Comment: if there's an opensource work being done on such thing, it will be less cost/time to develop it, and thus, can release it free.

Comment: @VOX Did you find any soluition?

Answer (score 2):

[CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) seems to be what you are looking for. It is using WebKit and saves rendered pages in different formats. For example: `./CutyCapt --url=http://www.example.org --out=example.png`

Comment: CutyCapt does not seem to be useful for this because CutyCapt does not allow any kind of interaction. just serves static image and I am use lacks of javascript manipulated dom, i.e. wenn an ajax poll request is finished the picture have to be updated. I am not sure if you could be able to build such a streaming rendering server by using phatomjs event "onResourceReceived"

Answer (score 1):

The Opera Mini servers does not process the websites to images before sending them to phones, but [to OBML](http://www.opera.com/mobile/help/faq/#mobile).

Comment: That makes sense for a browser. You still need to process clicks on links etc. Doing that with some PNG image seems like a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this question is still unanswered and I am interested in such a solution too. Since there is nothing useful findable on the web, I will give it a try. Please understand this answer rather as a concept than a ready to use solution.

Imagine a simple workflow with no user interaction. User opens a website, your server loads the website, renders an image and serves the image to your mobile.

To be sure your image is up 2 date, you will need to update your image on any dom manipulation from javascript too. This is a tricky one because there is no javascript event like "domChanged". So what can you do?

I have tried to build a very small javascript and use it with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var i = 0;

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  page.render('stocktwits.' + (i++) + '.png');
};

page.open("http://stocktwits.com/home#people-and-stocks");
```

I am assuming that requested resources are potentially messing up with the dom. But this is not covering any pure javascript setInterval or setTimout function.

Once you got all the "passive" stuff, you can try to extract any hyperlink, form elements and all elements styled with "cursor: pointer;". This is the point where I am stuck right now ... and since this is more a "hobby project" I am going to give up here :-) But let me know if anyone is going further on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar open source project [Browsh](https://www.brow.sh), which displays web pages in a Terminal, using true color blocks for images. This significantly reduces data usage. There is even a hosted version at [html.brow.sh](https://html.brow.sh), although the Terminal version has more features.